# JSONify a list of lists

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have a list of lists in python:

```
[["blue1", "blue2", "blue3", "blue4"], ["blue5", "blue6", "blue7", "blue8"], ["blue9", "blue10", "blue11", "blue12"], ["blue13", "blue14", "red", "blue15"]]
```

When I call json.dump on this list and then JSON.parse it in javascript, I do not get the equivalent list in in javascript. Any suggestions?

In python I have the dumps statement:

```
test = [["blue1", "blue2", "blue3", "blue4"],["blue5", "blue6", "blue7", "blue8"],["blue9", "blue10", "blue11", "blue12"],["blue13", "blue14", "red", "blue15"]]
        return render_template("game.html", test = test);
```

In html I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

</style>
<body>

<div id ="container">
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}" test = "{{test|tojson|safe}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In script.js I have:

```
var board = document.currentScript.getAttribute('test');
console.log(board[0][0]);
console.log(board[0][1]);
console.log(board[0][2]);
console.log(board[0][3]);
```

Console returns a [, then three undefineds

Comment: Can you show what you do get?

Comment: So how are you dumping and loading? Without code and output you do get, there is nothing we can tell you other than *use `json.dumps()` and `JSON.parse`*.

Comment: Added more information!

Comment: First of all, you pass in the data as `board`, but the JS loads `test` fed by a template variable `test`, that doesn't match. You are escaping the data to be HTML safe, and without quotes, here: `test = {{test}}`.  If this is Flask, don't dump to JSON in the view, use `test = "{{test|tojson|safe}}"` instead.

Comment: See [the relevant documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/templating/#standard-filters).

Comment: I corrected the discrepancy between board/test but the tojson is still not working. (See above.) The resulting array does not have strings in it.

Comment: You only get the attribute (which is a string), you never parse it into an array. So board[0] is just the first character of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You only get the attribute (which is a string), you never parse it into an array. So board[0] is just the first character of the string. Use JSON.parse,

```
 var board = JSON.parse(document.currentScript.getAttribute('test'));
```

However, there is another problem: you use the `|safe` template filter to turn off auto escaping. But JSON *is not safe*, for instance it contains `"` characters. If your HTML reads `test="[["blue1"],` et cetera, the value of the test attribute is `"[["`. So you need to remove that filter too so that Django can escape those quotes for you.